# How to add multiple relations in one operation in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I have a function like this:

```
void addRelation(string userId,List<string> friends)
{}
```

I want to add relation between userId and element in friends. Now my solution is add relation for each pair, but i found it with low efficiency. How can i add multiple relations in one operation like batch processing?

Comment: You should give some more context to your question: What programming language are you aiming for? Do you use Neo4j server or in embedded mode? How do you resolve the nodes representing a user by his userId?

Comment: sorry to forget the missing context,i'm using c# and use Neo4j server mode. All the parameters are userId, and first i will look up the two users, if not exist, create user with corresponding userId,then add relation between the two users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following answer is not based on C# and it takes the assumption that you're running on Neo4j 2.x.

The easiest way to solve is probably using a single Cypher statement with parameters:

```
MERGE (u:User {userId:{userId}}) 
FOREACH (f in {friends} | MERGE (u)-[:FRIEND_OF]->(:User {userId:f}))
```

The parameters (in JSON notation) are:

```
{"userId":"u1", "friends": ["friend1", "friend2"]} }]
```

Using the first `MERGE` you make sure that the node for your user exists (if you're sure it does you might replace `MERGE` with `MATCH`). The second line iterates over your `friends` parameter and creates the target node for each friend (unless it exists) and connects the user with the friends.

Due to my lack of knowledge on C# I don't know how you send Cypher statements to your server but I can give you an example using the `httpie` command line http client using the transactional http endpoint of Neo4j:

```
http -b -j localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit statements:='[{"statement": "MERGE (u:User {userId:{userId}}) FOREACH (f in {friends} | MERGE (u)-[:FRIEND_OF]->(:User {userId:f}))", "parameters": {"userId":"u1", "friends": ["friend1", "friend2"]} }]'
```

Comment: Thanks very much! It sounds just what i need. But i can't have a test about it now because it's Saturday, so i'm not in the company. Next Monday i'll test it as soon as possible. Thanks again~I'll accept the answer after making sure it is right

Comment: Hi,Stefan. I do what you suggest and it works. but i found that the time that the function cost will increase. for example: for(int i=0;i<10;i++) addFriendsRelation(); maybe the first call cost 0.5 second, but the last call my cost 5 seconds. i think it should be same in average but i can not figure it out. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I find the problem. It seems to create node for every id in friends when adding relation. It seems the MERGE in foreach useless?

Comment: When you're sure that the friend node already exists, you can use `MATCH (friendNode:User {userId:f}) CREATE UNIQUE (u)-[:FRIEND_OF]->(friendNode)` instead inside the `FOREACH`. (have not verified this, but should work)

Comment: could you please write it completely if use match and create unique? I don't know how to declare f if not using foreach